# exporting .txt files in html, and then importing it afterwards

Tags: html

So im making a website, and one of its core features I need to get working is getting the web page to export a mundane .txt file containing all the content from the forms I have.
Once that works, I also need to figure out how to import that same file back into the website and have it automatically fill in the text boxes.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kind of broad and doesn't show much research effort on your part. It's good form to have a go and then come here when you run into a problem, rather than just ask us to solve your problem for you. Despite that, I'll try to give you some pointers. :)

I recently had a requirement to make a button to download the contents of a div. I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/peacefixation/1650f98e8d497e0a758b5cccce71d37a) for future reference. You can probably adapt it to your purpose.

Basically what I did was assign a click handler to a HTML button marked 'Download'. When the button is clicked, I create a temporary anchor element on the page and set its `href` to the contents of the div and then programmatically click on the anchor to fire the download and finally removing the temporary anchor from the page. There's a fallback for Internet Explorer with a different method. I adapted this code from an SO answer some time ago.

```
var downloadButton = document.getElementById('downloadButton');
downloadButton.addEventListener('click', function () {

//get the contents of the div
var contents = document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML;

    if (contents.length = 0) {
        return;
    }

    var filename = 'some-filename.txt';

    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE
        navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([contents], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8;' }), filename);
    } else {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('download', filename);
        link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(contents));
        document.body.append(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
});
```

As for your next requirement, upload the file and importing the data, I'll direct you to the [HTML5 Rocks - file handling tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

I just had a crack at a quick file uploader and I have it dumping the file contents to the console. You could, instead, parse the file contents and add the data back to your form elements as required. Here's my test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test Page</title>

    <script>
        function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

            // Loop through the FileList
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

                var reader = new FileReader();

                // when the file has been read, print the contents to the console
                reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
                        console.log(evt.target.result);
                    }
                };

                var text = reader.readAsText(files[i]);
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So i got the your 'saving' code working, but it seems to export the html code within the form instead of the content of text boxes within said form.  Regardless, thanks for the help, and ill try to be less vague on my next question.

Comment: Right, you will have to play around with `var contents = document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML;` to make it get the elements that you want, and you probably have to encode the values of multiple form elements into a string that you can decode when you import it back in. This is just "the gist" as it were!